# Elasticsearch highlight with nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I have a question about highlighting nested object fields.

Consider record like this:

```
_source: {

    id: 286
    translations: [
        {
            id: 568
            language: lang1
            value: foo1 bar1
        }
        {
            id: 569
            language: lang2
            value: foo2 bar2
        }
    ]

}
```

If the translations.value has ngram filter, is it possible to highlight matches in nested object such as this one? 
And how would the highlight query look like.

Thanks a lot for response.

Comment: Hit the same problem today - it tells me I have a highlight (e.g. value: <em>foo2</em> bar2 when I search for foo2) but not simple way of tying that back to the source document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem over here. It seems that there is now way to do it in elastic search and won't be in near future.

[Developer Shay Banon wrote](http://www.searchworkings.org/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/150176%29):

> In order to do highlighting based on the nested query, the nested
>   documents needs to be extracted as well in order to highlight it,
>   which is more problematic (and less performant).

[Also](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Highlighting-on-nested-documents-if-include-in-parent-is-set-to-true-td4021717.html):

> His explanation was that this would take a good amount of memory as
>   there can be a large number of children. And it looks genuine to me as
>   adding this feature will violate the basic concept of processing only
>   N number of feeds at a time.

So the only way is to process the result of a query manually in your own programm to add the highlights.

**Update**

I don't know about tire or ngram filters but i found a way to retrieve all filter matching nested documents by using nested facets and facet filters. You need a seperate query for highlighting but its much faster than browsing through _source, in my case at least.

```
{"query":
    {"match_all":{}},
    "facets":{
        "matching_translations":{
            "nested":"translations",
            "terms":{"field":"translations.value"},
            "facet_filter":{
                "bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"translations.value":["foo1"]}}]}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the resulting facet terms for highlighting in your programm.

For example: i want to highlight links to nested documents (in jquery):

```
 setHighlights = function(sdata){
        var highlightDocs = [];
        if(sdata['facets'] && sdata['facets']['docIDs'] && sdata['facets']['doctIDs']['terms'] && sdata['facets']['docIDs']['terms'].length >0){
            for(var i in sdata['facets']['docIDs']['terms']){
                highlightDocs.push(sdata['facets']['docIDs']['terms'][i]['term'])
            }
        }
        $('li.document_link').each(function(){
            if($.inArray($(this).attr('id'),highlightDocs) != -1) {
                $(this).addClass('document_selected');
            }
        });
```

I hope that helps a little.

Answer (score -1):

You can use force_source" : true in the fields to cause the document be highlighted once nested fields are joined.